# Where to store db access password in winforms app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, security

My app is using a unique password to access a MS Access database.
Currently this is stored as plain text in a settings project.

What would be the best place to store this?

Thanks,
Alex

P.S. A colleague recommends source code obfuscation. What do you think?

Comment: I would save in same place just encrypt the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look into the `ProtectedData` class. There's a good [article here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx) about how to encrypt passwords and store them in the `app.config` file, although you should be able to use the same approach wherever you store your passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Code obfuscation itself doesn't help you there since it's a method to hide the intend of your code by renaming classes, methods and properties. You're looking for encryption. Various code obfuscation tools also offer an option to encrypt literal strings.

- [More about Obfuscation (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at google "recover access database password" you can see that password is not a protection for mdb. Maybe it is better to encrypt critical data inside WinForms application (for example by application user passwor - not mdb user password) and then store encrypted data to mdb.